# error with Submenu in XML file

Tags: android, xml, menuitem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
<item 
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:title="Main Menu"
    />

     <item 
    android:id="@+id/takesurvey"
    android:title="Take Survey"
    />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/viewstats"
    android:title="View Statistics"
    />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/changesort"
    android:title="Change Sorting Order "
   <menu>
     <item 
        android:id="@+id/create_new"                  
             android:title="@string/create_new" />    
          <item 
             android:id="@+id/open"                
             android:title="@string/open" />
   </menu>

     />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/menuexit"
    android:title="Exit from program "
    /> 
</item>
```

Hello , this seems to be a simple problem.I am trying to create a submenu ( for the change sort option ) in my XML file for android. However , I am geting an error :Element type "item" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". Any ideas?

Comment: Look at your highlighted code block. One `item` is highlighted black. Looks suspicious, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is a mess

You've got this open tag, with no closing tag:

```
<item >
```

You then have this, which is a partial tag:

```
<item 
android:id="@+id/changesort"
android:title="Change Sorting Order "
```

I suggest you reformat your XML to indent every sub-tag, and make sure every tag either ends with /> or a closing tag pair.

Comment: but i have a /> ( for item ) just after  </menu>

Comment: The second piece of XML I quoted is an open tag. You have not clsoed the XML tag. You need to go back to your XML reference and re-read - your XML is malformed and will not work in any way, shape or form. It is wrong, and incorrectly structured. It is not XML.

Comment: Specifically Ollie is saying that you either need to close the <item> tag with a </item> tag, or have a self-closing tag <item ... />.  <item> ... /> is not valid XML.  Also, as he says, review the android XML menu structure as well.